# How do I make a boolean method using a string?

Tags: java

This is what I have so far, I managed to reach here with several hours of work. The problem with my code is that if i give it a string "abcefg" it will verify the first two characters and returns it as true. I want the code to do it for all of my characters. I thought that putting the limit as x.length() would do the thing, but for some reason, it won't work.

Comment: Never `return true`. Only `return false`. That way you return on the first non-consecutive set but otherwise continue.

Comment: well if I don't return true, how does my program know it is true ?

Comment: How does it now it's `false` now? Just reverse everything.

Comment: Is `aba` consecutive?

Comment: No aba is not consecutive. @BoristheSpider, i removed the return true and what I got is that my string went out of range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static boolean ConsecutiveCheckerAscending(String x) {
x = x.toLowerCase();

for (int i = 0; i < x.length() - 1; i++) {
    if ((int)x.charAt(i) + 1 != ((int)x.charAt(i + 1))) 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}

public static boolean ConsecutiveCheckerDescending(String x) {
x = x.toLowerCase();

for (int i = 0; i < x.length() - 1; i++) {
    if((int)x.charAt(i) - 1 != ((int)x.charAt(i + 1)))
    {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
}
```

Comment: I just realised, this doesn't work for the reverse order. ex : cba will return false

Comment: Edited to add a Descending Order Method

Answer (score 1):

You have a variety of issues here.

Firstly, you can eventually go out of bounds with the `charAt(i + 1)` calls (check your loop condition).

Secondly, how can you possibly return true in the body of the for-loop? You haven't checked all of the characters yet!

I think you're making this overly complicated, though. All you need to do in order to check that two contiguous (i.e. next to each other in the string) characters are consecutive is

```
Math.abs(s.charAt(i) - s.charAt(i + 1)) == 1
```

You actually don't even need a cast. What we're doing is checking that the "distance" between the two characters is 1.

Just apply that to every contiguous pair of characters in the string, and return false if it isn't satisfied somewhere along the line. If you exit the loop without ever returning false, you can return true.

Comment: I tried it, and like you said I went out of bounds. Should i change it to i< x.length() + 1 ?

Comment: @VescoPro It should be `i < x.length() - 1`, since adding 1 to `i` should always keep it in bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Wrote it in a rush, but it'd look something like this.-

```
public static boolean ConsecutiveChecker(String x) {
    boolean consecutive = true;

    x = x.toLowerCase();        

    for (int i = 0; i < x.length() - 1; i ++) {
        if ((int) x.charAt(i) + 1 != ((int) x.charAt(i + 1))) {
            consecutive = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    return consecutive;
}
```

Comment: What's the point of your `consecutive` flag? Why not just `return`?

Comment: Well, I suppose I'm just get used to have just one return sentence at the very end of my methods.

Comment: I tried this, and whatever I input as string, it gives me false =/ thanks for the try though this program took me much more time than i had expected.

Comment: My bad, just updated my answer with the method fixed.

Comment: I appreciate that :) As for me, it's ok to accept @JohnBartels answer, the point is that other users can spot the right one. Remember that to reward other useful answers, you can always upvote them.

Comment: I just realised, this doesn't work for the reverse order. ex : cba will return false

Answer (score 0):

You cannot know for sure if the string is consecutive until the end of the method, so you cannot return `true` in the middle. At most you can return `false` when you find that string is not consecutive.

To give more advice, what do you mean by "consecutive"? Is `adgkm` consecutive? Looking at the current code it would look like it; all you check is the order of the characters. Is `abcdcbcd` consecutive? Usually "consecutive" means there are no gaps.

Comment: abcdefg is consecutive or gfedcba is also consecutive and 123456 is consecutive.

Comment: OK, what about abcba?

Answer (score 0):

In both if and else statements you having return statement, So the method will return after first check. You have to give return only for the exit condition. don't give for both if and else